# Tensorflow Regression Network: NaN values in epoch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, regression, lstm

I am working with a dataset of 13000 rows. I have used tensorflow to train a regression network to predict the target variable(Normalized using MinMax scaler). The architecture of the network looks like:

```
def build_vanilla_lstm(MAX_SEQ_LEN = 100, EMBEDDING_DIM = 100, DROPOUT_RATE = 0.5,EPOCHS = 100, BATCH_SIZE = 128 ,VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2,embedding_matrix=None):   
 
  np.random.seed(42)
  tf.random.set_seed(42)
  NUM_FEATURES = len(features_train[0])
  # Load pre-trained GloVe embeddings
  #embedding_matrix = {} 
  # Define input layers
  input_text = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LEN,), dtype='int32')   # Padded Essay Tokens
  input_features = Input(shape=(NUM_FEATURES,), dtype='float32') # Input Features

  # Define embedding layer
  embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0],
                              output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM,
                              weights=[embedding_matrix],
                              input_length=MAX_SEQ_LEN,
                              trainable=False)
  
  # Define LSTM layer
  lstm_layer = LSTM(units=64, activation='relu')  #also tried sigmoid
  # Connect input layers to embedding and LSTM layers
  text_embed = embedding_layer(input_text)
  text_lstm = lstm_layer(text_embed)
  # Concatenate LSTM output with input features
  concat_layer = concatenate([text_lstm, input_features])
  # Define dropout layer
  dropout_layer = Dropout(rate=DROPOUT_RATE)
  # Connect concat layer to dropout layer
  dropout_output = dropout_layer(concat_layer)
  # Define output layer
  output_layer = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')   
  # Connect dropout output to output layer
  output = output_layer(dropout_output)

  # Define model with two inputs and one output
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_text, input_features], outputs=output)

  # Compile model
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001),   
                loss='mse',
                metrics=['mae'])
  return model
```

```
EPOCHS = 100 
BATCH_SIZE = 128
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2

lstm_model = build_vanilla_lstm(MAX_SEQ_LEN = 100, EMBEDDING_DIM = 100, DROPOUT_RATE = 0.5,EPOCHS = 100, BATCH_SIZE = 128 ,VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2, embedding_matrix=glove_embeddings)
lstm_model.fit([padded_essay_train, features_train], target_train,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)
```

The results looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ0FZ.png)

I have tried using sigmoid and relu activtiation functions on the dense layer, also tried to reduced learning rate, batch size and increase drop out rate. My dataset does not have any NaN values, and target varibale is also normalized.

How to fix this issue? I have checked other stackoverflow responses as well but none of them are working with the above architecture.

Comment: is `embedding_matrix` defined?